# GoCD compare output in json in bash

Tags: go-cd

My situation is that i need to be able to get the gocd compare result in the form of json in bash, so that i can extract the commit ids from the output.

```
https://<go server url>/go/compare/<pipeline name>/<old build>/with/<new build>
```

The output of the above url in a GET (with authentication is an html document).

However i need to be able to get this in JSON format so that i can fetch the commit ids list from the comparison page output. Please suggest if there are any ideas.

Comment: Issue posted here : https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/3624